# Extra condition in switch case (Fallthrough?)

Tags: c#

I need to use an extra condition in a switch case in C#. Let's say that we have a couple of cases that required to do Stuff A and B, but case 4 requires Stuff C + Stuff Extra:

```
public void myFunction(int value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 0:
            //Stuff A
            break;

        case 1:
            //Stuff B
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            //Stuff C

            //Am I forced to use an If to a special condition of case 4?
            if(value == 4)
            {
                //Extra stuff for case 4
            }
            break;  
    }
}
```

**Is there another way to do it without using an If statement?**

Comment: Not sure what problem you are fixing, but you can use a `switch` if you want to...

Comment: extract the common `stuff C` code in a function, do it in cases 2 and 3, and do it in case 4 with the extra stuff.

Comment: No there is no way in c#, switch fallthrough is disallowed. Btw, it should be `value == 4`, not `value = 4`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It seems like OP wants a *partial fallthrough* in the switch.

Comment: It won't be much "switch-y", but @Rotem, you *can* fall through to a different case in C#, with `goto case 5;`. However, the way the code is organized, with the special case for 4 *after* the code for 2 and 3, it will not be possible to do that, since you cannot *call* a switch case. Do what Shark said, put the common code in a method and call it.

Comment: I don't see why there are downvotes on this question. It's a perfectly reasonable and clear question with a non-obvious answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a solution with goto and it actually works. Thank you for your answers:

```
 public void myFunction(int value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
               case 0:
                     //Stuff A
                     break;
```

`case 1:
                     //Stuff B
                     break;

               case 2:
               case 3:
                     //Stuff C
                     break;

               case 4: //Requires "Extra stuff" and "Stuff C"
                     //Extra stuff for case 4
                     goto case 3;

               //another possible cases...
               case 5:
                    //etc 
                    break;
        }
    }`

**Please notice that this solution will only work in cases that do NOT require a concrete order in the execution of the statements.**

If for example in this case "Extra stuff" must be executed after "Stuff C" the correct way to do it is using an If statement inside case 3.

Comment: I disagree with Patrick's advice to *never* use `goto`. We added "goto case" for precisely this situation, and so this is the situation you should use it in. That said, as Patrick suggests, there might be a way to write your code more elegantly without a `goto`. Consider for example: `switch(value){case 0: StuffA(); break; case 1: StuffB(); break;  case 2: case 3:  StuffC(); break; case 4: StuffC(); StuffD(); break; …`  That is even more clear than the `goto case` technique but it requires that your logic be extractable to methods.

Comment: If this works for you then this is a perfectly good solution. The only part which you have to verify is that in the example in the question, the common code for 2-4 executed before the special case for case 4, and in this piece of code, the special case code executes first.

Comment: Yes indeed, @eric-lippert, that way is more clear if another person has to take a look to the code, but in my case it's not worth it extract the statements into methods because they are just one line long and I want to "associate" both cases (strings with the name of asp pages).          lasse-vågsæther-karlsen , yes I already realize that and added a note in my solution, _goto_ may not be suitable for all cases.

Comment: If it is one line then what are you worrying about? CTRL-C, CTRL-V, done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of an odd one, combining local functions with switch:

I **DO NOT** recommend writing this code:

```
void Main()
{
    int value = 4;
    switch (value)
    {
        case 0:
            //Stuff A
            break;


        case 1:
            //Stuff B
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
            common234(); void common234()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2-4");
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            common234();
            Console.WriteLine("only 4");
            break;

        //another possible cases...
        case 5:
            //etc 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly (or, really, I really mean *luckily*), Duff's Device cannot be written in C#.